# Approximation of a characteristic function by continuous, bounded, and non decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $x \in{} \mathbb{R}$, I want to know if there exists a sequence of bounded continuous and non decreasing functions $(g_n)_{n \in{} \mathbb{N}}$ that converges pointwise to the characteristic function $1_{(x,\infty)}$ .

Comment: How about just $(1 - n^{-1})_{(x,\infty)}$? These are bounded,non-decreasing, and converge pointwise to the function in question (also, from below) as $ n  \to \infty$. Then you can make it continuous by just adding a line segment to the x-axis at the point $(0,0)$ (can make it more precise, but it obviously exists). In fact, I think you can even get smooth functions with the property. (i.e. bounded, non decreasing, converging to the characteristic function).

Comment: Let $g_n$ be zero up to $x$ ($x$ included), then draw a line from $(x,0)$ to $(x+\frac 1 n,1)$ and then continue with constantly one.